# Killing form of complexification of a Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying Helgason's *Differential Geometry and Symmetric Spaces*, trying to understand real forms of Lie Algebras.

My problem is related to Lemma 6.1 (1st edition):

Let $K_0$ be the Killing form of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and $K$ the Killing form of the complexification Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}$. Then
$$K_0(X,Y) = K(X,Y)~~\forall X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$$

**My problem**:

Understanding the previous equation as $K(X,Y)\equiv K(X+i0,Y+i0)$ I would get twice the result stated in the book. This is due to the following facts.

- $\text{ad}_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\in \text{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}})$, acting as
  $$\text{ad}_{\mathbb{C}}(X) [A+iB] = [X+i0,A+iB]_{\mathbb{C}}= [X,A]+ i [X,B] $$
  therefore I can write it as a direct sum of the *real* adjoint map
  $$\text{ad}_{\mathbb{C}}(X) = \text{ad}(X)\oplus \text{ad}(X)$$
- $\text{Trace}[\text{ad}_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\circ \text{ad}_{\mathbb{C}}(Y)] = \text{Trace}[\text{ad}(X)\circ \text{ad}(Y)\oplus \text{ad}(X)\circ \text{ad}(Y)] = 2\text{Trace}[\text{ad}(X)\circ \text{ad}(Y)]$

**Background**:

- Helgason's definition of complexification: $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}} = \mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g} \simeq \mathfrak{g}\oplus \mathfrak{g}$ with the complex structure
  $$J:(X,Y)\equiv X+iY\mapsto (-Y,X)\equiv -Y + i X$$
  extending the Lie bracket by $\mathbb{C}$-linearity:
  $$[X+iY,Z+iT]_{\mathbb{C}} = [X,Z]-[Y,T] + i [X,T]+i[Y,Z] $$
- Killing form of any Lie algebra over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$:
  $$B(X,Y) = \text{Trace}[\text{ad}(X) \circ \text{ad}(Y)] $$
  where $\text{ad}(X)$ is the $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $[X,\cdot]$.

Comment: The question boils down to this: you have $T: V \to V$ a linear endomorphism of the real vector space $V$. When complexifying, you get another linear operator $T_\mathbb{C} \colon V_\mathbb{C} \to V_\mathbb{C}$. What is $\operatorname{tr}(T_\mathbb{C})$? If you consider $V_\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space, you indeed get that $\operatorname{tr}(T_\mathbb{C}) = 2 \operatorname{tr}(T)$. But you need to consider it as a complex vector space, so a $\mathbb{C}$-basis for $V_\mathbb{C}$ will be half the size of an $\mathbb{R}$-basis.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see where I got it wrong: I didn't specify how I was taking trace: as real or complex vector space. I managed to prove that the complexification of an endomorphism has the same matrix expresion when using a real basis $e_k$ for $V$ and $e_k + 0i$ as a complex basis for $V_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$K(a,b)=Tr(ad_a\circ ad_b)$ a basis of $g$ induces a basis of $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $ad_a\circ ad_b$ have the same matrix in both basis.

Comment: I tried writing it down and it works: using ${e_k}$ as a real basis for $\mathfrak{g}$ and ${e_k + 0 i}$ as a complex basis for $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Consequently, there has to be a fundamental flaw in my reasoning, that I am yet to discover. 
Thank you for your help!